# Compiling LLVM 3.3 with GCC5, undefined references to c11 type signatures

Tags: gcc, llvm, gcc5

I'm having trouble compiling my project to use LLVM 3.3* with GCC5. I get undefined references, such as `llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTripleabi:cxx11'

The abi tag indicates it's an issue of mismatched ABI with GCC5. I know there's something I can do with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI`, but I don't understand why it isn't working. Both my projedt and LLVM are being compiled with the same GCC.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

**I am in the process of upgrading, but want to get the current dev version working before I upgrade to the new LLVM version. I upgrade my dev machine to Ubuntu 16.04 which hs the new GCC on it.*